# Java input error with decimal

Tags: java, input, decimal

I'm new to Java and I try to run this code and fill in as answer `5.5` or any number with a decimal and I got an error

Code:

```
System.out.print("What grade did you get?");
double number1 = input.nextDouble();
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
```

If I use a normal number without a decimal it works good.
Am I using wrong `input.next()`?

Comment: How did you declare `input`?

Comment: Works for me... what locale are you in? Perhaps it's expecting 5,5?

Comment: Yes it does work with 5,5 but not with 5.5 Jon Skeet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes it does work with 5,5 but not with 5.5 Jon Skeet

Yes, then set a locale

```
System.setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```